# Would it be a bad practice to mix fgets with scanf and use fseek to skip the new line characters? C

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, stdio, fseek

I want to use `fgets` and `scanf` mixing them, but there are leftovers of `'\n'` characters and they mess up the `fgets` output, I've tried using:

```c
fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
```

And it worked, is this a bad practice?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:iostream].

Comment: 1) Even if `fseek` "works", it is not portable since `stdin` is not guaranteed to be a seekable stream. 2) If it works as you seem to imply it does, it is not equivalent to skipping over just a `'\n'`. 3) If you end each `scanf` format string with a `' '` space, it will consume any following whitespace, including newlines.

Comment: this not guaranteed to be a seekable stream it's because of the operating system?

Comment: Files are (usually) seekable, characters typed on a keyboard are not.

Comment: @GuillemVS It's a matter of language standard, not OS support, as elaborated in the posted answer.

Comment: @dxiv yes yes! I posted the comment before seeing the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of `fseek` with `SEEK_END` isn't defined by the C standard.

[7.21.9.2/4 The fseek function](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p4):

> For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be SEEK_SET.

Even otherwise, It's unreliable to use fseek on `stdin`. POSIX says *streams* with no backing files (pipes, sockets, etc) are not seekable.

But you're attempting a "wrong" solution in my view: don't mix `fgets` and `scanf` to start with.

`scanf` is fragile for user inputs and proper [error handling of `scanf` is hard](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). You might instead use just `fgets` to read lines and use `sscanf` to extract inputs.